# Onclick function get id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something that can be varying id's. I want to call a function of the present id. This is what I have (which is unresponsive):

```
approvebutton = present_item.append("<div class='tableItem'><a href='#' id='"+itemIndex+"' onclick(alert(this.id))>"+ "approve" +"</a></div>");
```

Comment: are you using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.tableItem > a').on('click', function(){
    var $link = $(this);
    console.log("This is my id: "+ $link.attr('id') );
    //do stuff with the link
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick needs to be formatted like so:

`<div class='tableItem'><a href='#' id='test' onclick="(alert(this.id))">"+ "approve" +"</a></div>`

As a best practice I'd recommend against using the onclick attribute but rather binding via a script.

Answer (score 0):

trying onclick="alert(this.id)", run code below.

```html
<div id="someId" class="presentItem" onclick="(alert(this.id))">click me
</div>
```